# Spree Commerce: Location of GEM file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, spree

I am newbie to Rails development and working with Spree Commerce bitnami Stack VM instance. I am trying to install spree extension and the instructions says to make configuration changes to application Gem file which I cannot find in the webserver directory

Running Rails 2.3.5
 Spree 0.9.4 version

Comment: Hi, can you point to instructions? The application is in the installation directory apps/spree

Comment: Like this one on Github https://github.com/spree/spree_store_credits.It says add "gem spree_store_credits" to GEM file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why you can't find it because Gemfile is a standard from Rails 3+ and you're using a Rails2 app. Rails3 uses Bundler which takes cares about all Gems for your app.

In Rails 2 gem dependency definition is different. It doesn't have Bundler so "bundle install" also won't work in your case.

Instead you need to add Gem dependency to config/environment.rb like this:

`config.gem 'your_gem_name_here'`

also you need to install the Gem manually, so not like in Rails3 where Bundler installs it. Use this in shell:

```
gem install your_gem_name
```

In general it's a good idea to update the app to Rails3, I'd recommend it because as I saw this Gem you wanna use doesn't have earlier release.